Draw an specific image with Tikz
How can I draw this image with TikZ?

I write this code but can't complete that. My idea is drawing a Polygon and repeat that with rotate:
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw] at (0,0) {};
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,shift={(.3 cm,.3 cm)},rotate=90] at (0,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Please choose a title which describes the actual problem you face so that future users with the same problem will be able to find it.

A solution with the regular polygon shape is valid but it needs you to figure out the incircle or the circumcircle. In your case, all sides are equal so drawing a polygon with a given side length seems easier.
The disadvantage is that every corner gets each own coordinate (instead of them being anchors).
The key Regular Polygon = <name>@<initial angle>:<number of sides> draws a regular polygon with <number of sides> sides (or corners) where the first side has angle <initial angle>. All corners are named (<name> <i>) where <i> starts from 0 and goes to <number of sides> − 1.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  Regular Polygon/.style args={#1@#2:#3}{
    insert path={             coordinate (#1  0)
      \foreach[count=\j from 1] \i in {0, ..., \inteval{#3-2}}{
        -- ++(#2+360/#3*\i:1) coordinate (#1 \j) } -- cycle}},
  vh/.style={to path=|-(\tikztotarget)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, Side Square/.style={draw=blue!70!green!70}]
\draw (0, 0) [Regular Polygon= 6w@  0:6]
      (6w  3)[Regular Polygon=6nw@-30:6]
      (6nw 2)[Regular Polygon= 4n@  0:4]
      (4n  1)[Regular Polygon=6ne@-30:6]
      (6ne 2)[Regular Polygon= 6e@240:6]
      (6w  1)[Regular Polygon=6sw@-90:6]
      (6sw 3)[Regular Polygon= 4s@  0:4]
      (4s  1)[Regular Polygon=6se@-30:6]
      (6sw 4)[Regular Polygon= 6m@  0:6]
      [behind path, every edge/.append style={Side Square, vh}]
        (6w 4) edge (6nw 5)
        (6e 5) edge (6ne 3)
        (6w 0) edge (6sw 1)
        (6e 3) edge (6se 2)
      pic (x) [draw, fill=gray,
        pic text=, pic text options=coordinate] {angle=6sw 5--6w 1--6w 2};
\draw[-{Triangle[angle'=45]}] (x) -- ++ (left:2) node[left]{?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


You can also work with the shapes.geometric-library:

\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\a{20.35mm}% polygon side length
\def\n{6}% fix
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\R{0.5*\a/sin(180/\n)}% outer radius n-polygon
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\r{0.5*\a/tan(180/\n)}% inner radius n-polygon
\pgfmathsetmacro\middlepointangle{360/\n}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
myshape/.style={inner sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize, align=center},
>=latex, 
]
\foreach \y in {0,...,2}{%%
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}{%
%
% Which Figure? ==================
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Fig{%
mod(\x,2)==0 && mod(\y,2)==0 ? 1 % Square
: (mod(\x,2)==1 && mod(\y,2)==1 ? 0 % nothing
: 2)% 6-Polygon
}% =============================
% Coordinates and Rotation-Angle ==========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\X{\x*(0.5*\a+\r)}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\Y{-\y*(0.5*\a+\r)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\y+1,2)*0.5*\middlepointangle}
% ==============================
\def\mytext{%x\x,y\y; 
S\x\y \\ Fig\Fig 
}% optional
% 
%
\ifnum\Fig=0 \else
   \ifnum\Fig=1 % Square
    % Square
  \node[myshape, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, draw,
minimum size=sqrt(2)*\a, 
   ] (S\x\y) at (\X,\Y) {\mytext};
  \else%  (\Fig=2)
    % Polygon
  \node[myshape, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,
  minimum size=2*\R,
  rotate=\rotangle
  ] (S\x\y) at (\X,\Y) {\mytext};
\fi\fi%
}% end of x-foreach 
}%% end of y-foreach 

%% Annotations ===============
\coordinate[] (A) at (S12.corner 1);
\coordinate[] (B) at (S01.corner 5);
\coordinate[] (C) at (S01.corner 6);

\draw pic [draw, angle radius=8mm, fill=lightgray,
local bounding box=myangle,
] {angle =A--B--C};
\draw[thick, ->] (myangle.center) -- +(-1.5*\R,0) node[left]{?};

% Tests
%\draw[red] (S00.south west) -- +(\a,0);
%\draw[brown] (S01.corner 6)  circle(3pt);% Test
%\draw[red] (S01.corner 5)  circle(3pt);% Test
%\draw[orange] (S12.corner 1)  circle(3pt);% Test
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

